# numpy.minimum for complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

numpy.minimum does not seem to work for complex numbers:

```
np.minimum(5+3*1j,4+30*1j)
(4+30j)
```

I want to keep the value with the maximum magnitude.
It only compares the real part.  Any other function for elementwise minimum comparison? MATLAB min does work with complex numbers.
Thanks

Comment: First thought use `np.absolute` to calculate magnitude and then compare result in `np.minimum`

Comment: Comparison of complex numbers in mathematics is undefined.
No one can tell if one number bigger or smaller than another.  
But You may compare absolute value (length) of vector, as RobJan said (but this is not real comparison of complex numbers - this is comparison of absolute values).

Comment: Which is why Python's implementation is more transparent than MATLAB's one.

Comment: MATLAB uses the magnitude of complex numbers when using `min` or `max`.  It's in the documentation but it's buried.

Comment: Min and max use sort order -- try `zsort = np.sort( z ); print( z.min(), zsort[0], z.max(), zsort[-1] )`.  The [doc for numpy sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) says "The sort order for complex numbers is lexicographic", i.e. sort by .real then by .imag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.abs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)

Suppose you have

```
vals1 = [4+30*1j, 7+3*1j, 4+30*1j]
vals2 = [5+3*1j, 6+3*1j, 5+3*1j]
```

then

```
>>> np.where(np.abs(vals1) > np.abs(vals2), vals2, vals1)
array([5.+3.j, 6.+3.j, 5.+3.j])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare complex numbers by magnitude, you can use built-in `abs` and then compare results:

```
>>> np.minimum(abs(5+3*1j),abs(4+30*1j))
5.830951894845301
```

To get a minimal initial number instead of its magnitude, use [argmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
>>> nums = [5+3*1j, 4+30*1j]
...
>>> nums[np.abs(nums).argmin()]
(5+3j)
```

Comment: Instead of just stating, maybe it would be better to write how to get the initial number using argmin

Comment: This is how MATLAB compares complex numbers so this is the closest to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
X = np.array([3+4j, 10+5j, 1+1j])
min_X = min(X, key=np.abs)
print(min_X)
Out: (1+1j)
```

Comment: Interestingly, `numpy.min` itself does *not* allow `key`.

Comment: Yep, interesting really. Can't really comment on which is faster because of that