# Use tensorflow reduce max on complex numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have this tensor:

```
h = tf.constant([1.+2.j, 3 + 4.j])
```

And i want to use the tf.reduce_max on it:

```
tf.reduce_max(h)
```

I will have the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of complex128 is not in the list of allowed values: float, double, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, half, uint32, uint64, qint8, quint8, qint32, qint16, quint16
    ; NodeDef: {{node Max}}; Op<name=Max; signature=input:T, reduction_indices:Tidx -> output:T; attr=keep_dims:bool,default=false; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, 12026250066093653660, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_QINT16, DT_QUINT16]; attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]> [Op:Max]
```

Where, when I am trying with numpy there is no error:

```
h_array = np.array([1.+2.j, 3 +4.j])
np.max(h_array)
>>>(3+4j)
```

How can I make it work on tensorflow.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Numpy only compares the real part of the complex numbers (compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481376/numpy-minimum-for-complex-numbers)).

So you should probably try `tf.reduce_max(tf.math.real(h))`